# Subversion's path-based authorization Project Hosting

Tags: svn, authz

Is there any free project hosing service that provides path-based authorization ?
Google code and Xp-Dev do not seem to support this feature. I need this feature since I'm teaching a subject where students can upload their assignments. However, one student can not commit to other student's working directory. Thank you.

Comment: Is own VisualSVN Server an answer?

Comment: Thank you but no, it's not :D If I have money to host a SVN server, I would select a commercial project hosting service that supports the authorization feature.

Comment: 1. You'll **not find** SVN-hosting with path-auth. 2. I host [my personal repos](http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/) on Celeron 2.4